# iPhone post-processing with a single FBO with Opengl ES 2.0?

Tags: iphone, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, post-processing

I am trying to implement post-processing (blur, bloom, etc.) on the iPhone using OpenGL ES 2.0.  I am running into some issues.  When rendering during my second rendering step, I end up drawing a completely black quad to the screen instead of the scene (it appears that the texture data is missing) so I am wondering if the cause is using a single FBO.  Is it incorrect to use a single FBO in the following fashion?

For the first pass (regular scene rendering),

- I attach a texture as COLOR_ATTACHMENT_0 and render to a texture. 
  **glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D, texturebuffer, 0)**

For the second pass (post-processing),

- I attach the color renderbuffer to COLOR_ATTACHMENT_0   **glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_RENDERBUFFER, colorRenderbuffer)**
- Then use the texture from the first pass for rendering as a quad on the screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that FBO usage is fine. The cause is very likely to be that you didn't set the MIN/MAG filters of your texture (texturebuffer), after binding, set the GL_MIN_FILTER and GL_MAG_FILTER to GL_NEAREST or GL_LINEAR using glTexParameter, and your texture should be working.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  Is there a resource that you could point me to that would confirm such usage?  (Not that I don't believe you, but it would likely be an excellent reference.)

Also, I have already set the MIN/MAG filter, so it must be something else.  Are there any other common pitfalls you can think of?

Comment: As commented below, the problem was similar.. my texture was not being sized to a power of 2.  Your answer got me looking in the right place, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As Matias states, your design looks fine.  I've done something similar myself and had it work well.

I wrote a sample application which uses shaders to process camera images, which can be downloaded [here](http://www.sunsetlakesoftware.com/sites/default/files/ColorTracking.zip), but that uses `glReadPixels()` to pull offscreen values into a processing routine rather than directly mapping the result to a texture onscreen.  You might be able to modify it to do that.

Otherwise, I made a more complex shader sample application [here](http://www.sunsetlakesoftware.com/sites/default/files/ShaderExamples.zip) that in one part renders a scene to a cube mapped texture, then feeds that texture into a second stage of processing.  This should illustrate the rendering to, and use of, a texture with OpenGL ES 2.0 shaders.

Maybe these could shed light on where your implementation is failing.

Comment: The problem was that my texture was being sized to 320x480 rather than a power of 2 (512x512).  Thanks, the code was very helpful.