# CGImageRef from OpenGL ES framebuffer (iOS)

Tags: ios, opengl-es, framebuffer

How can I **efficiently** create a **CGImageRef** from the EAGLView's framebuffer contents using **glReadPixels**?  Perhaps I can "render directly to a texture"?

I'm relatively new to OpenGL ES so any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The function [`glReadPixels`](http://www.khronos.org/opengles/documentation/opengles1_0/html/glReadPixels.html) is very expensive... if you want to render to a texture you could take a look at:

- [iPhone post-processing with a single FBO with Opengl ES 2.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4712042/iphone-post-processing-with-a-single-fbo-with-opengl-es-2-0)
- [Rendering to texture on iOS OpenGL ES—works on simulator, but not on device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7313734/rendering-to-texture-on-ios-opengl-esworks-on-simulator-but-not-on-device/7385548#7385548)
- [Writing to then reading from an offscreen FBO on iPhone; works on simulator but not on device?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4110023/847363) (answer is at end of question...)
- http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1704/_index.html
- http://www.visualnewt.com/OpenGL/learning_iphones_opengl_es/
- http://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glCopyTexImage2D.xml

For a reference of OpenGL ES on iOS see http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/3DDrawing/Conceptual/OpenGLES_ProgrammingGuide/Glossary/Glossary.html